# Dynamically exposing WebPart connections at runtime

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, web-parts

I'd like to try and expose some connections for a webpart at runtime, at compile time I don't know what they are, and I'm wondering if anyone can provide any suggestions on where to start. 
All the examples I've read seem to do so statically using `[ConnectionConsumer]` and `[ConnectionProvider]` which obviously needs to be done in code, I don't however know what I need to expose at this point in time.

My use case would be something like a grid that uses a DataTable. The DataTable is retrieved by using a SQL statement:

```
select * from myTable
```

The connections I want to expose are when this changes to

```
select * from myTable where columnA = myConnection1
```

At this point I want to expose a connection for my WebPart called 'myConnection1', if I add multiple where clauses I want multiple connections that can be linked from other WebParts.

**EDIT**
An example of this would be like how ReportingServices within SharePoint handles connections. It seems to use a custom WebPartManager that determines at runtime the number, names and types of connections that need exposing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I determined that the best way was to use the IWebPartParameters interface and expose them manually.

http://blog.mindbusiness.de/blog/2011/09/05/implementation-of-iwebpartparameters-web-part/

Answer (score 0):

You can create connections between web parts dynamically:

```
wpMgr.ConnectWebParts(wp1, cp1, wp2, cp2)
```

Ted Pattison: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188696.aspx#S6

Not sure what is dynamic in your question:

-the schema of the data that flows through the connections OR

-the creation of these connections from provider to consumer web parts at runtime?

Hope this helps?

Comment: The dynamic part is the number and name of the connections, because they need to change as the SQL changes. I wish them to be connected on the web, but I need to ensure the correct connections are exposed for selection.